# Special Vector and Element-wise Multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays. "A" is one of them with arbitrary length (let's assume 1000 entries for a start), where each point holds a **n**-dimensional vector, where each entry represents a scalar. "B" is the other one, with **n** entries that each hold a 3-dimensional vector. How can I do a scalar multiplication, so that the result is one array "C", where each entry is the scalar multiplication of each of the **n** scalars with each of the **n** 3-Dimensional Vectors?

As an example in 4-D:

```
    a=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],....]
    b=[[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]]
```

and a result

```
    c=[[1*[1,0,0],2*[0,1,0],3*[0,0,1],4*[1,1,1]] , [5*[1,0,0],...],...]
```

The implementation should be in numpy without to large for loops, because there are expected to be way more than 1000 entries. **n** is expected to be 7 in our case.

Comment: Please be careful with the usage of `numpy.array` and `list`. These are different data structures. For example `np.array([0,1,0]) * 2` results in `np.array([0,2,0])`, while `[0,1,0] * 2` results in `[0,1,0,0,1,0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start with:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
b = np.array([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,1,1]])
```

Then we can add an extra axis to `a`, and repeating the array along it gives us...

```
>>> a[:,:,None].repeat(3, axis=2)
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6],
        [7, 7, 7],
        [8, 8, 8]]])
```

Now, as @Jaime says, there is no need to use the `repeat` while operating, because NumPy's broadcasting takes care of it:

```
>>> a[:,:,None] * b
array([[[1, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 0],
        [0, 0, 7],
        [8, 8, 8]]])
```

Comment: You don't need the `repeat`, broadcasting will take care of it, i.e. `a[..., None] * b` gets you the same, only faster.

Comment: Yeah... I was using `repeat` just to figure out the right axis to add and forgot to remove it.

Comment: Beautiful and easy...thanks. We tried figuring something out with `repeat`, but that simple idea of adding an axis did not come up.